# How to use a value produced in another do block?

Tags: haskell

I just watched a video on Haskell so I tried to play a little bit with it but I can't get to understand this (In short I want to print one random value):

```
import System.Random
import System.IO

randomNum = do
   gen <- newStdGen
   let ns = randoms gen :: [Int]
   let val = take 10 ns 
   print $ head val

writeToFile = do
    theFile <- openFile "test.txt" WriteMode
    let val = randomNum;
    hPutStrLn theFile ("Random number " ++ randomNum)
    hClose theFile

readFromFile = do 
    theFile2 <- openFile  "test.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents theFile2
    putStr contents
    hClose theFile2
```

The randomNum seems to work fine but when I try to put that on writeToFile it triggers an error. What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The error I get in the beginning is:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell.hs, interpreted )

haskell.hs:207:48:
    No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of `show'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show randomNum'
    In the second argument of `hPutStrLn', namely
      `("Random number " ++ show randomNum)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      hPutStrLn theFile ("Random number " ++ show randomNum)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell.hs, interpreted )

haskell.hs:207:48:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `IO ()
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `randomNum'
    In the second argument of `hPutStrLn', namely
      `("Random number " ++ randomNum)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: if all you want is one value, you can just write `val <- randomIO :: IO Int`, or `val <- randomRIO (1::Int, 10)` to get it in a specific range (here, from 1 to 10, inclusive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
import System.Random
import System.IO

writeToFile = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    let ns = randoms gen :: [Int]
    let val = head ns;
    theFile <- openFile "test.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn theFile ("Random number " ++ show val)
    hClose theFile

readFromFile = do 
    theFile2 <- openFile  "test.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents theFile2
    putStr contents
    hClose theFile2
```

One problem was that the `do` block in your `randomNum` did not return a value; rather, it performed the action you told it to do: print a random number. As an alternative, see [Louis Wasserman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794909/edit) for a way to make randomNum actually return a value. In this answer's code, the random number generation was just moved into writeToFile.

Also notice that I shortened the code to get one random value: `ns` is already a list, so you can take its `head` right away. The `take 10` was redundant.

Finally, `val` was an Int, which cannot be concatenated directly onto a string. Using `show val` converts it to a string which can be concatenated with `"Random number "`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like what you need is

```
randomNum = do
   gen <- newStdGen
   return (head (randoms gen :: [Int]))

writeToFile = do
    theFile <- openFile "test.txt" WriteMode
    val <- randomNum
    hPutStrLn theFile ("Random number " ++ show val)
    hClose theFile
```

Comment: I tried it and I get "Couldn't match type IO () with IO () -> Int

Comment: It gives me an error but it's too long for a comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `show val` not `show randomNum`. Functions usually don't show very well...

Comment: When using this solution the error is Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell.hs, interpreted )

haskell.hs:207:44:
    No instance for (Show (IO Int)) arising from a use of `show'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show randomNum'
    In the second argument of `hPutStrLn', namely
      `("Random number " ++ show randomNum)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      hPutStrLn theFile ("Random number " ++ show randomNum)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>

Comment: That wwas fixed by @recursion.ninja's edit; it's `show val`, not `show randomNum`.